# Error with an insert in nodejs and Postgres using sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to do an insert in Postgres using sequelize, but I am getting this error:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

This is my controller:

```
const bcryptjs = require('bcryptjs');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var path = require('path');
const {OAuth2Client} = require('google-auth-library');
const {Model, Sequelize} = require('sequelize');
const db = require('../../models/index');

exports.signUp = async (req, res) => {

try{
    const newUser = await db.user.create({
        first_name: "test",
        last_name: "test" ,
        email : "true",
        mobile_number : "true",
    })
    if(newUser){
        return res.json({message:"Movie created  successfully",data:newUser})
    }

}catch(errors){
    console.log(errors);
    res.status(400).json({
        ok: false,
        errors
    });
}

}
```

And this my model:

```
'use strict';
const {
Model
} = require('sequelize');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
const user = sequelize.define("user", {
// Model attributes are defined here
first_name: {
  type: DataTypes.STRING
},
last_name: {
  type: DataTypes.STRING
},
email: {
  type: DataTypes.STRING
},
mobile_number: {
  type: DataTypes.STRING
}
}, {
schema: "user"
// Other model options go here
});
return user;
};
```

I have a schema named "user" and a table named "users" in that schema created in postgres. I deleted the table in postgres and I did the migrations again but I am getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

In your second image you are using `sequelize.define('user')`, try changing it to `sequelize.define('users')`. You are defining a table that does not exist.

Comment: I tried changing that in the model but I got:
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined

Comment: Change `const new user = await db.users.create` as well

Comment: It would be better if you add your source code rather than adding images.

Comment: I added the code. I changed const new user = await db.users.create but I got the relations error, the same that I have at the beginning

Comment: Done, solved by using this in the model:
freezeTableName: true